# Can't seem to be able to run .jar file from command prompt

Tags: java, jar

I'm pretty new to Java and I'm sure this is a noob question but I really can't get this to work.

I have a simple java file with some dependencies that looks like this:

```
package myFilePackage;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.util.*;

public class myclass{

    public static void modifySomeFile(arg1, arg2, ...){
    //Function that uses the above dependencies
    ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        for( arg : args){
            System.out.println(arg);
        }

        //my code works fine up to here!

        modifySomeFile(arg1, arg2, ...);
    }
}
```

Basically, what happens is that it prints all the arguments just fine when I call it from the command prompt, but never calls the modifySomeFile function.

This is how I call it from the prompt:

```
cd C:\path\to\file java -jar myjar.jar arg1 arg2
```

Here's my manifest file (I read somewhere that it might be the problem)

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: myfile.myClass
```

Here's the path to my class:

```
myfile/myClass.class
```

Also, there's only one class in my jar file.

Comment: Why are you using a jarfile from the command line if you only have one class?

Comment: `myfile.myClass` ... this implies that the package is `myfile`, which it clearly is not based on the source code you posted.  And if the package were `myfile`, then you should be running the JAR from the level _above_ this location.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry, edited I copied the path of my .java file before I created the .jar file

Comment: @MDXF I've been asked to do it

Comment: Your package and path do no match up, this won't work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen wow, you're totally right, I created it using eclipse and it created a .jar for one of my other file. Created the right one and it works now. just write an answer I'll mark it as solved

Comment: @Charles I don't know what you did to fix it, no worries, glad you resolved the problem.